# Laravel 4 phpseclib shh2 exec and get output

Tags: php, laravel-4, exec, output, phpseclib

i will exec SSH2 commands in Laravel 4 and catch the output to print it on the screen.
But not on the same root as where is Laravel is running. I will exec the commands on other roots. Is see that Laravel is using phpseclib.

How can i use the same phpseclib functionality of this code but in laravel 4 format:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

I need the output of the exec.

Hope for help thx

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Hello, yes here is an example.

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('IP', PORT);

if($ssh->login('USER', 'PASSWORD')) {                    
    $output = $ssh->exec("ls");   
}

Comment: Oh, thanks, anyway I've found the ssh2 module for php is **much** faster, so I think I'll use that one instead. Maybe in case you want to use laravel on a shared hosting or in situations where you can't add modules to php, the laravel approach is better, otherwise I've seen a huge improvement about speedups with the php's module :)
Thanks anyway! :D